# How can I write a MySQL query where two tables have conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables...

```
contracts
---------
id

contract_locations
------------------
id
contract_id     # A contract can have many contract locations.
name            # E.g., "Front office", "Legal", "Contracts admin", etc.
arrival_date
```

Users consider the location with the last `arrival_date` to be a given contract's "current location".

They want to be able to find all contracts with a current location `name` equal to (for example) "Front office" or "Legal".

How can I write a MySQL 5.1 query to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select c.id
from (select c.*,
             (select name
              from contract_locations cl
              where cl.contract_id = c.id
              order by arrival_date desc
              limit 1
             ) CurrentLocation
      from contracts c
     ) c
where CurrentLocation = 'Front Office'
```

This uses a correlated subquery to get the current location.  Performance will be much improved by having an index on `Contract_Locations(contract_id, arrival_date)`.

Here is another method that may be less obvious.  The idea is to see if the most recent date is the most recent date for a given location.  This uses a `having` clause:

```
select contract_id
from contract_locations cl
group by contract_id
having max(arrival_date) = max(case when name = 'Front Office' then arrival_date end)
```

The `having` clause is only true when `'Front Office'` (or whatever) is the most recent date.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT contract_id
FROM contract_locations l
JOIN (SELECT contract_id, MAX(arrival_date) curdate
      FROM contract_locations
      GROUP BY contract_id) m
ON l.contract_id = m.contract_id and l.arrival_date = m.curdate
WHERE l.name = 'Front Office'
```